# Entity Framework Code First // Foreign key to a unique key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is it possible to add a foreign key via Entity Framework Code First, that references not a primary key, but just a unique key?

Comment: I particularly love the first comment: "Guyz, srsly?" https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/299